# Mercurial: warn when adding files which would otherwise be ignored?

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

How can ask Mercurial to warn me before I add files which would otherwise be ignored?

For example, something like:

```
$ hg add foo.o
warning: adding ignored file foo.o
```

There seems to have been a patch submitted to the mailing list: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2008-February/004993.html

But I can't find any further references to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's sort of a hacky workaround and only half what you want, but you could replace

```
$ hg add foo.o
```

with

```
$ hg add -I foo.o
```

That says "add everything but only if it's not ignored **and** it matches the pattern after `-I`".

An example:

```
$ ls -A
.hg  .hgignore  this
$ cat .hgignore 
this
$ hg stat --all
? .hgignore
I this
$ hg add -I this
$ hg stat --all
? .hgignore
I this
```

So you can see that "this" wasn't added and is still in ignored state.  Of course, that's not a warning, it's a refusal.

Comment: Dunno about the OP, but I liked this. It works pretty well when you want to do `hg add foobar*` and it adds foobar.py, foobar_test.py and the otherwise-ignored foobar.pyc (for example). With this trick it does the expected and ignores the pyc file.

Answer (score 3):

Use `hg addremove`. It will not add ignored files.
Extract from [addremove documentation](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#addremove)

> New files are ignored if they match any of the patterns in .hgignore. As with add, these changes take effect at the next commit.

Answer (score 0):

This won't help much on add, but you could catch it during commit by using a 
[pretxncommit](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html#sec:hook:pretxncommit) hook.